# jQuery writing a if...else statement

Tags: jquery

So, I have these conditions that I need to write `if...else` statement for js. I have been at it for 3 hours but really cannot figure out how to do it properly.

So, I have two forms: `Form-A` and `Form-B`. There are two scenarios:

**1. Form-A is clicked first:**

1. If `Form-A` is clicked again, then don't do anything
2. If `Form-B` is clicked, then do something

**2. Form-B is clicked first**

1. If `Form-B` is clicked again, then don't do plaything
2. If `Form-A` is clicked, then do something

Writing a `if-else` statement for one scenario is easy. But I am having a hard time writing a `if-else` statement that can accommodate two scenarios. I can have as many variables as it needs.

I was thinking of changing a `var` dynamically.

Anyway, could someone help me out with this?

Comment: If neither Form-A or Form-B have been clicked yet, and someone clicks on one of them, should they do anything?

Comment: Well, it is under an assumption that one of the forms has already been clicked. :P

Comment: It seems to me that you want to be able to click either form in any order, one time each. If so, then @guest271314's answer (with my edit) will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to denote which is clicked last:

```js
var lastClicked;

function a(){
  if(lastClicked != 'a') {
    lastClicked = 'a';
    alert('A clicked');
  }
  else {
    alert('nope, nothing happens when you click me again');
  }
}

function b(){
  if(lastClicked != 'b') {
    lastClicked = 'b';
    alert('B clicked');
  }
  else {
    alert('nope, nothing happens when you click me again');
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="a()">A</button>
<button onclick="b()">B</button>
```

---

Single-handler version (for Jeremy):

```js
var lastClicked;

function h(b){
  if(lastClicked != b) {
    lastClicked = b;
    alert(b + ' clicked');
  }
  else {
    alert('nope, nothing happens when you click me again');
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="h('a')">A</button>
<button onclick="h('b')">B</button>
```

Comment: OP wants 1 `if...else` that can accommodate both scenarios

Comment: I will see if I can use this method. At this point, I am willing to use any method :P

Comment: @Jeremy, it is a single `if...else` just in two handler functions. It can be easilty rewritten into one function with one parameter, and still only one `if...else`. I thought the two-handler version would be easier to understand.

Comment: Well, that's what you asked for, @Jeremy. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.one()`

```
var clicks = 0;

function check() {
  ++clicks;
  if (clicks === 2) {
    // do stuff
  }  
}

$("form:eq(0)").one("click", check);

$("form:eq(1)").one("click", check);
```

From the OP's requirements it seems that this can be simplified into:

```
function doStuff() {
  // do stuff
}

$("form").one("click", doStuff);
```

Comment: This looks good but you don't even need the `clicks` variable. He wants to be able to run both forms in either order one time, you get that with just using the `one()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your HTML is setup but I'll assume you have only two forms  and you are clicking the form container to select the form.

```
$('form').on('click', function(){
   if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')){
      $('form.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      //do other things...
   };
});
```